# Porque eu não consigo maximizar a janela no segundo monitor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fullscreen

Estou tentando maximizar a janela do wpf no segundo monitor, mas a janela fica maximizada no monitor principal quando inicia.

Se eu tirar a linha que maximiza a janela vai aparecer no segundo monitor normalmente, mas vai ter pequenos espaços e não vai estar totalmente preenchido. Eu precisava maximizar no segundo monitor, inclusive sobrepor a barra de tarefas.

Eis o código

```
public partial class View02 : Window
{
    public View02()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showInMonitor(1, this);
    }

    public void showInMonitor(int monitor, Window window)
    {
        List<Screen> screens = Screen.AllScreens.ToList();
        if (screens.Count > 1)
        {
            Screen screen = screens[monitor];
            if (!window.IsLoaded)
                window.WindowStartupLocation =
            WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            window.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
            window.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
            window.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
            window.Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

Porque esse código não maximiza a janela no segundo monitor??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em WPF, se vc define o `WindowState` para `Maximized`, seja no XAML ou no construtor, então a sua janela sempre vai aparecer no monitor principal e não no secundário.

Para isso eu estive vendo esse [**site**](http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2008/01/maximizing-wpf-window-to-second-monitor.html)

Ali mostra que precisamos maximizar a janela depois que ela é carregada

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, salvou meu dia!